# How to know if your browser is connected to the Ipv4 or Ipv6 address of a website?

Tags: ipv6, internet-explorer, google-chrome

Is it possible to know if a browser (Internet Explorer/Google Chrome in Windows 7 SP1) is using the IPv4 or IPv6 address of a website? What I'm looking for is for some kind of visual feedback without resorting to netstat -an or some other tricks outside the browser itself?

Comment: well, if i'm asking, the answer obviously have some value to me. i would guess that it may also have some value for other people. if it does not matter to you, that´s ok, but IMHO this does not reduce the value of the question and more importantly the value the answer may bring to me and some other lost soul that maybe be wandering the same...

Comment: I can imagine multiple scenarios where it does matter. For example, you encounter problems with some service you are maintaining, IPv6 is lot slower in your network (and therefore it's useful to know why something is slow) and so on.

Comment: Many sites have both A and AAAA records and it's very important to know which ones is the browser using when you're setting up IPv6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly what you asked, but there is [plugin for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/showip/). It's not as cool as it could be, but by default it shows IPv4 addresses as red and IPv6 addresses with green font.

Comment: just wanted to add for some future soul searching for the same answer that google-chrome has an extension called ShowIPv6

Comment: Searching for ShowIPv6 now gives an extension called IPvFoo, which does the job very nicely.